# Unable to configure Azure Data Factory to get data from http endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to use Azure's data factory http connector, but I cannot go past step 2 (connection source), as, when I press the 'next' button, I get the error 'File schema is not defined'.

As can be seen on the attched picture, I get a 400 error from the server, but, when I execute the same get with postman, I do not get any errors from the server and I can download the file (which is an xlsx file, perhaps that is the problem).[image]

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood well your question I assume you are referring the UI Copy Activity flow (you are using the http connector for that purpose). If you can't detect or manually set a schema for your document, would binary copy work for you? 
On the first page of step 2 you will find the Binary Copy checkbox that may solve your problem.

Comment: That is actually what i was looking for, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

here you select the format with 'Text format', not sure your request result is csv or not.

> If you want to retrieve the data from an HTTP endpoint as-is without parsing it, skip the format setting.
>
> If you want to parse the HTTP response content during copy, the following format types are supported: TextFormat, JsonFormat, AvroFormat, OrcFormat, and ParquetFormat. For more information, see Text format, JSON format, Avro format, Orc format, and Parquet format.

This is the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-http-connector